# Add column with within-subject rank-ordered interaction day in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a large pyspark dataframe containing user interaction data for a multi-year period. There are many columns, but the three useful ones for this question are `userid`, `interaction_date`, and `interaction_timestamp`. Assume there are multiple entries for a given user in the table.

I need to write a function to add a column that will indicate the number of days prior to the latests observed interaction for a given customer in the table. For example, for an input table

[image: example_table_1]

I'd like to add a column that counts up from the most recent interaction date for that user (e.g., the most recent interaction date is 1, the next-most previous interaction date is 2, etc.):

[image: desired_output_table]

Can anyone steer me toward the right way to do this?

Comment: Please avoid [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6664872) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok! I tried to build a table manually first, but it rendered quite garbled :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with a [window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) function like [dense_rank](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank). Have a look at the comments below:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cols = ['userid','interaction_timestamp']
data =[( '1'        ,'2018-01-02' ),
( '2'        , '2018-01-03' ),
( '1'        , '2018-01-03' ),
( '1'        , '2018-01-04' ),
( '2'        , '2018-01-02' ),
( '3'        , '2018-01-03' ),
( '4'        , '2018-01-03' )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

df = df.withColumn('interaction_timestamp', F.to_date('interaction_timestamp', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

#rows with the same userid become part of the the same partition
#these partitions will be ordered descending by interaction_timestamp
w = Window.partitionBy('userid').orderBy(F.desc('interaction_timestamp'))

#dense_rank will assign a number to each row according to the defined order
df.withColumn("interaction_date_order", F.dense_rank().over(w)).show()
```

Output:

```
+------+---------------------+----------------------+ 
|userid|interaction_timestamp|interaction_date_order| 
+------+---------------------+----------------------+ 
|     3|           2018-01-03|                     1| 
|     1|           2018-01-04|                     1| 
|     1|           2018-01-03|                     2| 
|     1|           2018-01-02|                     3| 
|     4|           2018-01-03|                     1| 
|     2|           2018-01-03|                     1| 
|     2|           2018-01-02|                     2|
+------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks!